# Как дописать код, чтобы программа полностью закрывалась при нажатии определенной клавиши?(python)

Tags: python

Мне нужна программа автокликер, которая бы: 
-начинала кликать по нажатию клавиши ЛКМ
-останавливала клики по нажатию клавиши 'q'
-полностью закрывалась по нажатию клавиши 'w'

Первый вариант кода:

```
import mouse, keyboard
from time import sleep

while True:
    if mouse.is_pressed(button='left'):
        sleep(0.01)
        mouse.double_click(button='left')
```

Второй вариант, улучшенный, выходит из цикла по нажатии "q":

```
import mouse, keyboard
from time import sleep

while True:
    if mouse.is_pressed(button='left'):
        while not (keyboard.is_pressed('q')):
            sleep(0.01)
            mouse.double_click(button='left')
```

Третий вариант, который тоже не работает:

```
import mouse, keyboard
from time import sleep
flag = True
while flag == True:
    if mouse.is_pressed(button='left'):
        while not (keyboard.is_pressed('q')):
            sleep(0.01)
            mouse.double_click(button='left')
    if keyboard.is_pressed('w'):
        flag = False
```

Comment: Sys.exit() я пробовал, не помогло

Comment: У вас что-то странное проверяется. Но второй код должен завершаться, если нажать `w`. А вот если нажать левую кнопку мыши, то оба кода будут крутиться в цикле пока не будет нажата клавиша `q`. Что в реальности ваш код должен проверять вообще?

Comment: @CrazyElf это программа - автокликер, изначально код без строки `while not (keyboard.is_pressed('q')):` , и чтобы цикл остановить, она была добавлена, и следующим этапом я хочу по нажатию клавиши не просто останавливать цикл на 'q' но и закрывать программу на 'w'

Comment: я все еще надеюсь, что помощь придет

Comment: В первых двух вариантах у вас просто не предусмотрено выхода. А третий должен выходить, если просто нажать `w`. Либо сначала `q`, а потом `w`, главное чтобы ЛКМ не была нажата всё время.

Comment: Так у вас этот кликер вообще не работает или только не выходит из программы?

Comment: все работает, просто из него неудобно выходить, так как у меня открыто два окна: первое это IDE, второе это приложение в котором нужно кликать. Я нажимаю F5 в IDE и открывается командная строка в которой стартует программа-кликер, после чего нажимаю ALT-TAB чтобы перейти в приложение в котором нужно кликать, и когда я накликал то что мне нужно, я хочу чтобы после нажатия "w" эта КОМАНДНАЯ СТРОКА закрылась

Comment: получается, я ввел в заблуждение и неправильно задал вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов решения:

```
import mouse, keyboard
from time import sleep
flag = True
while flag == True:
    if mouse.is_pressed(button='left'):
        while True:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
                break
            elif keyboard.is_pressed('w'):
                exit()
            sleep(0.01)
            mouse.double_click(button='left')
    if keyboard.is_pressed('w'):
        flag = False
```

Comment: Круто! Как сделать, чтобы консоль еще закрывалась, а не выводилось 'Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .'.

Comment: @y3x3la Нужно импортировать библиотеку `sys` и заменить `exit()` на `sys.exit()`

Comment: импортировать библиотеку `sys` и заменил `exit()` на `sys.exit()`, ничего не изменилось

Comment: Почему-то сегодня чтобы выйти из программы нужно нажать два раза на `W`. Первое нажатие останавливает цикл, и только второе выходит из программы с выводом сообщения  'Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .'